# Android to MS SQL Connection Error

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc, mobile

I am trying to connect my local MS Sql from Android.

Here is the code sample:

```
String ip = "999.999.9.9";         /* Local IP address */
String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String db = "Mydbname";
String un = "username";         /* Without Laptop name, instance name */    
String password = "Password";    
String instance ="SQLEXPRESS";

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
        z = "Please enter User Id and Password";
    else {
        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Error in connection with SQL server; please check all input values";
            } else {
    """
```

When executing the above MainActivity.Java, we are getting the error message

> Error in connection with SQL server; please check all input values

Tried with and without instance SQLEXPRESS word and laptop name.

How to get the local MS SQL Server connection established from Android Studio and MainActivity.Java?

Build.Gradle has proper 'implementation' dependencies. Also app manifests got relevant uses-permission too.

What exact values/inputs to be passed to get the connection to the local MS Sql database table?

Comment: You're getting that message because your `connectionClass.CONN()` method is returning `null`.  Without knowing what's in that method, we can't help you.  Besides, it's not a good idea for an Android app to connect directly to a SQL database (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231500/how-do-i-access-databases-from-a-mobile-device-securely).  Put a REST API in front of the database and connect to that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is an experiment to start with to see how the mobile app is getting connected with MS SQL. Not a real project at the moment. Will do REST API later when things are working out. Since the connection is returning null, the error message is getting displayed. So wanted to know what changes to be done either in the input values or in the code. I think there is no issue from the code.

Comment: I could not give the code here due to the char restriction in the comment. protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        edtuserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtuserid);
        edtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpass);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) {
                DoLogin doLogin = new DoLogin();
                doLogin.execute("");
            }
        });
    }
    public class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;
        String userid = edtuserid.getText().toString();
        String password = edtpass.getText().toString();
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,r,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(isSuccess) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddProducts.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }

Comment: @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
                z = "Please enter User Id and Password";
            else
            {
                try {
                    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                    if (con == null) z = "Error in connection with SQL server; please check all input values";
                    } else {
                        String query = "select *   /* code till the error msg*/

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, been having computer problems.  Instead of posting code in comments, please edit your question to include the code.  Besides, even taking a brief look at the code you have posted in the comments I can't see any method named `CONN()`, nor the definition of the class `ConnectionClass()`.  As I see it, that is where the error is.